# Quiz Game Development

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a quiz game that'll be used at anime conventions. 
Using a laptop and a wifi point, the plan is to let the audience use their phones as the answer selecting device. Player number will be based on IP address.The client screen will basically display buttons for answer 1,2,3, and 4.

I'm using MYSQL and PHP on the server. I have a few tables such as:

- **Questions** :where the acutal questions are listed along with the correct answer. The fields for this are id| Q_text|Ans1|Ans2|Ans3|Ans4|Cor_Ans|Image_Path
- **Quizzes** :has ID and quiz name.
- **Quiz_Questions** :this table has the fields for having multiple questions be apart of multiple quizzes.
- **Control** :this has the admin user account(not worried about security since this won't be online and will be only for prizes of candy), game name (so it can be changed if other people use it).

The problem I have is how do I get the list of questions for the current quiz (use quiz #4 and get the list of questions in that quiz) and show only the current question then go to the next one with a button press.

Like I said, security is not an issue. They're only winning candy and the system will not be only.
I also need to have a table that will contain all of the submitted answers for the current question. With that, I can make a nice pretty pie chart that'll display answer percentages when I display the correct answer. Hopefully this all makes sense.

Edit: I'll be providing the wifi point. Closed network, password protected so the only ip's handed out will be to those in the room.
Also, I'll be choosing the quiz. Client only gets to select an answer. The question I select will be displayed on a projector for all to see. The audience selects their answers. I hit next, it shows the correct answer, candy is handed out, and then I hit next question. This all continues until we run out of questions in the current quiz or we end the quiz early. Then I'll have a list display who had the most correct answers total and we give out a big prize.

Comment: Player number by IP address is not a good idea.  In many cases, several users will have the same public IP address.  This is likely to especially be true at a conference with a lot of folks using the same WiFi.  Use session IDs instead.

Comment: Can the user select the quiz? If so you'll want a list of quizzes, each with a query string specifying the quiz ID. From that, you can look up the quiz questions from the database, and render them to the quiz page.

Comment: I suspect the OP means that they will provide their own wifi point, in which case each user would indeed get their own IP on a private LAN. But, I agree that sessions are generally better, with no downsides.

Comment: IP-based on phones using cellular data is a BAD idea. Given the IPv4 shortage, it is **HIGHLY** unlikely you'd see anything but NAT gateway addresses for the users when on cellular data. If it was wifi-based, you'd probably be ok.

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How to write SQL? How to write PHP? Criticism of the schema? Something else. (IMO: You are going to need another field (question_number) in quiz_questions in order to determine the **next** question)

Comment: A single question can appear in more than one quiz. Is that your intention? If not, then I suggest you merge `Questions` and `Quiz_Questions` to become a single table.

Comment: @AgRizzo: I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around keeping track of the current quiz and determining what the next question is.

Comment: As I suggested, add another column to the quiz_questions table called question_number. You know what quiz everyone is taking, you should know what the current question is. (Assume in the quiz_questions table  the current question has the question_number of 5. Now you know you need the same quiz's question #6.)

Comment: This can't possibly answered in a succinct manner here. You are basically asking us how to write an application.

Comment: @MikeBrant No. I just need to figure out _how_ to keep the current question in memory as well as keep track of what question is next. The rest of the application will be easy and I already have my documentation written up for it. It's just the flow of things that has me at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get from the database the question which corresponds to current quiz.. right?
You could create a PHP page which take the current quiz id (so every quiz should have an unique ID) and then return every question with the quizID = quiz_passed.

```
SELECT question_content FROM questions WHERE quizID = currentQuiz
```

Something like this.

After you get questions, you can store it somewhere (an ArrayList maybe? or LinkedList or what you want.) you can take it from the array and put the question inside the screen.

You can get the answer in the same way. Based on the question id you can select answers.
Maybe you can create a class to manage the question.

This would be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by AgRizzo, give each question in the quiz a sequence number.

```
SELECT q.*
FROM Questions q
INNER JOIN Quiz_Questions qq ON qq.QuestionID = q.ID
WHERE qq.QuizID = 11
  AND qq.SequenceNumber = 3
```

This example yields the third question of quiz #11.

Increase the parameter for `SequenceNumber` for the next question. The quiz is finished once the query returns nothing.